# Is it possible to rewrite any SQL query that uses temp tables, as a set-based query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, set-theory

Often, when working with complicated queries in SQL, I use one or more temp tables, to break the problem down into smaller pieces: I would create a new temp table or (table variable), persist some data to the temp table, use that temp table to create another temp table, and so forth. Until finally, I select from the last temp table as my output. The reason for this, is that with a very complex problem, a single set-based operation to get the final answer, is not always obvious.

I know that, generally speaking, temp tables are considered a sub-optimal solution, and can often be optimized by rather writing a purely set-based query (JOINs, WHERE clause, subquery etc.)

Can you re-write *any* SQL query that uses temp tables, as a purely set-based query?

Comment: *"Is there always a better performant set-based solution, for any given query that uses temp tables?"* No; for indexed temporary tables *can* improve performance (an example off the top of my head is when using linked servers and you want to limit the data sent from one server to the other).

Comment: Any resonable query can likely be rewritten without temp tables, but in the same way, you can probably chisel a Ferrari out of a rock with a fork too. Temp tables can be great, especially if you refer to some data multiple times. A query must often materialize that data every time, but if you put it into temp table, you can reuse the data. Also, temp tables can have own indexes that help with various fetches. One can use CTEs (common table expression) as a kind of a poor man temporary tables that mostly save you from typing

Comment: Always is a big word.  For example, recursive CTEs for large hierarchies can be expensive while a temp table approach can be dramatically more performant... so the answer is "It depends".   That said, there is no shame in temp tables.

Comment: At the same time, temp tables are often overused and badly indexed, so IMO should only be used where the execution plan indicates an optimization fence is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the theoretical standpoint you can always write a query that is based in intermediate results, as a single query using CTEs (Common Table Expressions).

For example, if you have three "real tables" X, Y, and Z, and you have 4 temporary tables to hold intermediate results, the process could look like:

```sql
create table a as select ... from x join y join z;
create table b as select ... from a join x; -- dependency on a
create table c as select ... from y;
create table d as select ... from a, b, c; -- dependency on a, b, and c
select from a join b join c join d; -- final query
```

The assembled query using CTES, can look like:

```sql
with
a as (select ... from x join y join z),
b as (select ... from a join x),
c as (select ... from y),
d as (select ... from a, b, c)
select from a join b join c join d;
```

From the practical standpoint, having materialized intermediate tables does have some benefits. For one, you can inspect and debug more easily.
Moreover, sometimes it can lead to increased performance if you index those materialized results appropriately.

The downside is that you are consuming [a lot of] tablespace. Also, when combined as CTEs, some engines are smart enough to "untangle" and fully reorganize (the technical term is "rephrasing the query") the set of queries in different ways that may be faster to execute, that may have not even though about; some engines are really smart in this sense. They can also pipeline intermediate result sets, in a way that you cannot do if you materialize them.

Overall, run your horses.

If you have bandwidth, try both and see which one is better for you. Sometimes the ability to debug intermediate result is paramount. Other times, performance is the driving factor. All depends on your use case.